# How to antialias strokes drawn in canvas without using clearRect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, antialiasing

I am working on a drawing app as a personal project (currently living at http://draw.ist/) and I'd like to get the drawn strokes smooth around the edges but it seems the only way to accomplish this is using clearRect. However, clearRect also clears the canvas every time I start a new path and I'd like to prevent that so the canvas actually accumulates the strokes.

I've seen stuff about creating a secondary canvas to save strokes to or something so the clear doesn't wipe them (at least I think it works somewhat like that) however that method would require a lot of additional code that I'd like to avoid. Most recently I've tried saving the canvas as an imageURL on mouseup and then re-placing it with drawImage right after every clearRect, and this seems to do the trick nicely but it has some bizarre interactions with my eraser and straightline tools, as well as some flickering every time it loads in the saved canvas image.

There isn't necessarily any particular snippet of relevant code here, but for reference the entire site can be found at http://draw.ist/ (Controls: hold shift to draw straight lines, hold spacebar to erase, scroll mousewheel to change brush size)

I'd like all drawn lines to be smooth and have antialiasing but without using the "secondary canvas as memory" method IF POSSIBLE. I think what could help me here as well is understanding why exactly clearRect is necessary to apply antialiasing to strokes in canvas and how it works exactly in layman's terms. I greatly appreciate any assistance on this, whether it's actually helpful or not!

Comment: That's the way its done my friend (`clearRect()`). Good luck reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I solved the issue by just creating a second canvas behind the primary one and using the same class and everything as the primary canvas, and then on mouseup just doing ctxMem.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0); to post to the "memory" canvas in the background. this works very effectively and was less than 10 additional lines of code, MUCH less than I had originally anticipated. Examples I was looking at were just overcomplicating things, so I had to dissect it to grasp the relevant bits.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. now you are only clearing the "drawing" canvas while appending to the visual one. Awesome! Have fun.